# Ajax loaded StumbleUpon badge not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, stumbleupon

I am adding social media buttons in an ajax call.  So far I have gotten all of my social media buttons to refresh with the exception of stumbleupon:

```
//Refresh Facebook
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('.socialWrapper'));

//Refresh Twitter
$.ajax({ url: 'https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true});

//Refresh LinkedIn
IN.parse()

//Refresh Pinterest
window.parsePins();

//Refresh Google Plus
$.ajax({ url: 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true});

//Refresh SU (Not Working)
$.ajax({ url: 'https://platform.stumbleupon.com/1/widgets.js', dataType: 'script', cache:true});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Nope.  The ajax loaded content with the SU div's just down not refresh with the badges.

Comment: Instead of the ajax reload you can try to refresh SU with `STMBLPN.wasProcessLoaded = false; STMBLPN.processWidgets();`

Comment: That worked great! If you want to add it as an answer I can award the bounty to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stumbleupon script only updates once the badges when the page is loaded. The script also has some checks to only do this for the first time when the script loaded so loading it again with ajax won't help.

The `widgets.js` also does not have any publicly documented nice re-loading API like LinkedIn or Pinterest.

However you can re-execute the badge updates with the following code, with changing the internal state of the `STMBLPN` object:

```
STMBLPN.wasProcessLoaded = false; 
STMBLPN.processWidgets();
```